# Can't end process in Task Manager, no error messages

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, task-manager, kill

I searched for question similar to this, but they all mentioned error messages in Task Manager.  I'm not getting any.

I could no longer open a new instance of either Firefox or Chrome after exiting them earlier by clicking on the X in the upper right corner.  Opening Task Manager I found I had two instances of Firefox running, and eight of Chrome.

I tried using End Task and End Process Tree to kill them, and this got rid of half -- I still had one Firefox and four Chrome processes that could not be deleted no matter what I did.  But no error dialog came up, the End Process command just silently did nothing.

I ended up having to reboot, and even that got stuck, it was showing "Shutting Down..." for  perhaps 10 minutes and I had to kill the power.  On powering back up, I expected the message "Windows did not shut down properly" but instead it went straight to the animated Windows logo.

This happens maybe twice a week to me, and usually associated with one of my browsers.

I am running Windows 7 SP1 64-bit with 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the browsers? Do you have many extensions in use?

Comment: Please also try resetting browsers. Examine windows startup programs and remove those (run msconfig in start menu search and use the startup tab). Do these instances run under your account or any other account such as system?

Comment: @Epoxy Thanks for the suggestions.  (and also to @Papa) I'm not sure what you mean by "resetting browsers" though.

Comment: Yes, you can reset IE, Firefox, Chrome all.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/923737
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en

Comment: Resetting the browser:
http://www.howtogeek.com/171924/how-to-reset-your-web-browser-to-its-default-settings/
Also you might check your cpu temp http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/ and video card drivers. I have seen some odd video card issues that pop up in web browser usage. Do your use the machine for anything else that might be taxing? Video playback? Does it freeze there as well?